How to track browser history back and forward events triggered by the address bar, keyboard binding or mouse button?
I would like to find out if a user is triggering the back and forward events in their browser history by one of these three methods:

clicking on the back and forward arrow buttons in the browser using their mouse
pressing the keyboard keys that is bound to these actions
clicking on the mouse buttons that is bound to these actions

Are these events tracked separately by the browser (if supported by all browsers)? And where do you have to capture these events so that you can then process and tally them up across a single browsing session?
